# SQL Select column-spanned data over row-spanned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
REPORT_MONTH    FORECAST_1  FORECAST_2  FORECAST_3  FORECAST_4  FORECAST_5  FORECAST_6  FORECAST_7  FORECAST_8  FORECAST_9  FORECAST_10 FORECAST_11 FORECAST_12
201501            23            23        14         51            25          27          28            29         36          35           12          42
201502            24            25        26         12            4           25          26            7           8          21           4           24
```

The above records sales forecast of next twelve months based on the starting month (EX: if report month is 201501, Forecast_2 refers to March of 2015's sales forecast)

Given this schema, I'd like to select data as following:

```
REPORT_MONTH    FORECAST_MONTH  FORECAST_VALUE
201501             201502             23
201501             201503             23
201501             201504             14
201501             201505             51
201501             201506             25
201501             201507             27
201501             201508             28
201501             201509             29
201501             201510             36
201501             201511             35
201501             201512             12
201501             201601             42
201502             201503             24
201502             201504             25
201502             201505             26
201502             201506             12
201502             201507             4
201502             201508             25
201502             201509             26
201502             201510             7
201502             201511             8
201502             201512             21
201502             201601             4
201502             201602             24
```

Barring the obviousness of having to convert the varchar dates into datetime, Is this even a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the nicest solution, but you could use a set of `union`s:

```
select report_month
,      substring(convert(varchar, dateadd(month, 1 /*month nr*/, convert(date, report_month + '01', 112)), 112), 1, 6) forcast_month
,      forecast_01 forecast_value
from   tableName
union
all
select report_month
,      substring(convert(varchar, dateadd(month, 2 /*month nr*/, convert(date, report_month + '01', 112)), 112), 1, 6) forcast_month
,      forecast_02 forecast_value
from   tableName
```

Etc, etc.

Comment: UNION ALL is the way to go, but you missed a few things. Add column number to REPORT_MONTH to get FORECAST_MONTH, and also FROM table is missing.

Comment: @jarlh: Thanks. You were right. It was just some sample code. I thought OP might figure out the rest himself. It was about the concept, not a 'write my code'.

Comment: No I'm not sure if this would work. For instance, if the report month is 201505, then forecast_1 refers to the value of 201506. With the above query, there is no way of distinguishing which month forecast_1 refers to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` for a more succint query:

```
SELECT REPORT_MONTH, FORECAST_VALUE, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REPORT_MONTH ORDER BY FORECAST) AS rn
FROM 
   (SELECT REPORT_MONTH, FORECAST_1, FORECAST_2, FORECAST_3, ...etc
    FROM #FORECASTS) p
UNPIVOT
   (FORECAST_VALUE FOR FORECAST IN (FORECAST_1, FORECAST_2, FORECAST_3, ...etc))AS unpvt;
```

The output produced from the above query is sth like:

```
REPORT_MONTH    FORECAST_VALUE  rn
----------------------------------
201501          23              1
201501          23              2
201501          14              3
....
201502          24              1
201502          25              2 
201502          26              3
.....
```

You can now wrap the above query in another query and use `rn`, `REPORT_MONTH` in order to calculate `FORECAST_MONTH`:

```
SELECT REPORT_MONTH, 
       DATEADD(MONTH, rn, CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(REPORT_MONTH, '01'))) AS FORECAST_MONTH, 
       FORECAST_VALUE
FROM (
   SELECT REPORT_MONTH, FORECAST_VALUE, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REPORT_MONTH ORDER BY FORECAST) AS rn
   FROM 
      (SELECT REPORT_MONTH, FORECAST_1, FORECAST_2, FORECAST_3, ...etc
       FROM #FORECASTS) p
   UNPIVOT
      (FORECAST_VALUE FOR FORECAST IN (FORECAST_1, FORECAST_2, FORECAST_3, ...etc ))AS unpvt
) t
```

Output:

```
REPORT_MONTH    FORECAST_MONTH  FORECAST_VALUE
----------------------------------------------
201501          2015-02-01      23
201501          2015-03-01      23
201501          2015-04-01      14
... etc
201502          2015-03-01      24
201502          2015-04-01      25
201502          2015-05-01      26
... etc
```